# Is it possible to filter JTable in a worker thread?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, event-dispatch-thread, worker-thread

I have a JTable with around 11000 rows and a search box used for filtering on regex. 
My code in the search box looks like this:

```
getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
    {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
        {
            final RowFilter<TableModel, Object> rf;
            try
            {
                rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(getText(), 0);
            }
            catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException exception)
            {
                logger.info("Failed to compile regex.", exception);
                return;
            }
            sorter.setRowFilter(rf);   
        } 
        .......
```

The problem is that the whole UI becomes unresponsive during the filtering operation. I suppose that this is because the filtering is done in the EventDispatchThread so
is there a way to somehow put the filtering in a worker thread?

Comment: hmm ... wondering: 10k rows aren't _that_ many, so the filtering shouldn't take long (as in perceptible). Maybe something not quite right in your model?

Comment: Well... actually my table model is retrieving its data at runtime from an osgi service. So it doesn's store the data in any way. Could this be a problem?

Comment: yeah, could well be: while sorting/filtering it will access the data often .. the mechanism is a kind-of cursor that walks across the tableModel. You should try to profile the app to find the exact bottleneck